# OkHttpClient response 206 exception

Tags: android, http-headers, okhttp

i am using OkHttpClient for an android application to download PDF files from a server , i got an exception for a pdf file  while downloading it.

```
System.err: java.io.IOException: 206
```

here is the response elements :

```
Date: Tue, 27 Nov 2018 12:45:17 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25
Last-Modified: Mon, 09 Jan 2017 16:06:27 GMT
ETag: "392a0c-545ab8ccd2dc8"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1
Content-Range: bytes 3746315-3746315/3746316
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/pdf
OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1543322716318
OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1543322716467
```

and this is the code used to dowloand the file :

```
private final static int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 8;
Request.Builder requestBuilder = new Request.Builder().url(itemUrl);

try {
        Response response = 
        getOkHttpClient().newCall(requestBuilder.build()).execute();

        long totalSize = response.body().contentLength();

        if (response.code() != 200) {
            throw new IOException(String.valueOf(response.code()));
        }

        RandomAccessFile out = new RandomAccessFile(tempItemFilePath, "rw");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(response.body().byteStream(), BUFFER_SIZE);

        long bytesCount = 0;
        int bytesRead = 0;

        try {

            out.seek(out.length());

            while (true) {
                bytesRead = in.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                if (bytesRead == -1) {
                    break;
                }
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                manager.setDownloadStatus(magazine, ((bytesCount * 100) / totalSize));
                bytesCount += bytesRead;



                EventBus.getDefault().post(new DownloadStatusUpdateEvent());
            }
        } finally {
            out.close();
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            in.close();
        }
        }
```

any idea why it's not working ? 
PS : it's working for files less larger than the one it's not downloading.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're doing a [range request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-1) asking for the last byte out of the 3746316 bytes composing the response.

In response to that you get a 206 status code, as per RFC 7233:

> The 206 (Partial Content) status code indicates that the server is
> successfully fulfilling a range request for the target resource by
> transferring one or more parts of the selected representation that
> correspond to the satisfiable ranges found in the request's Range
> header field (Section 3.1).

The reason why you get that exception is this piece of code:

```
if (response.code() != 200) {
    throw new IOException(String.valueOf(response.code()));
}
```

What you should check instead is if the response is successful (i.e. if it has a 2xx status), which can be done in this way:

```
if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
    throw new IOException(...);
}
```

Note though that your code will successfully create a `RandomAccessFile` with the content of the response, i.e. a single byte in this case, which is probably not intended.